# React JS (Ice js) Error: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, ice

I just used this code export `const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);`
I used it in my index.tsx
inside jsx component

```
  const [{ user },dispatch] = useStateValue();
```

I imported everything am still getting errors

which I think is responsible for error . anyways to solve it?

Link to repo :
https://github.com/dingus45191/Facebook-ice

I am using  alibaba's ice framework

Error:
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Comment: no errors in terminal just this on screen and console. No linter errors either. Not sure why I am getting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you you're trying to destructure an iterable

```
const [{ user },dispatch] = useStateValue();
```

when the value isn't an iterable.

I suspect you're setting the context value to an object, not an array and may want something more like

```
const { { user }, dispatch } = useStateValue();
```

if you're setting the context `value` as an object.